# I want to be able to remove a div element when the window is smaller than 900 px. How do I do that?

Tags: jquery, html

Here is the code I have till now: http://pastebin.com/X8WpUMy5

Comment: Why not just use a mediaquery and hide it via display:none?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use CSS media queries:

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
#sidebar {display:none;}
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you it worked. The thing is I knew about media queries, I was just unaware of the option of display: none.